# How to call Ssrs Reports into the dot net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, reporting-services

I want to call one ssrs report into asp.net when i give the  statdate and end date.Please any one help me with sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251671%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) control. Start & End Date will be report parameters and can be supplied to ReportViewer control along with other information such as SSRS url, report name/id etc.

See [this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252075.aspx) for configuring ReportViewer to use report from SSRS service.

Comment: Can you Please give me the sample code .... when i give the dates report will generate.

Comment: Ok, I am using jquery command propmt  i am giving the some amount in command prompt textbox when i click 'ok'  button in command propmt that perticular amount will add to the ssrs reports